# R610 Mixed Memory configuration

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge, ecc

The configuration for this question is as follows:

- We have two dell R10 servers.
- Each R610 is has 2 X E5504 cpus, (The E5504 is 4 core X 2.0 GHz).
- I ordered 12 sticks of 8GB ECC DDR3 ram ([Hynix HMT31GR7BFR4C](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT31GR7BFR4C&rk=20&rc=module)).
- I had 12 sticks of 2GB ECC DDR3 ram ([Samsung M391B5673EH1-CH9](http://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/m391b5673eh1-ch9/5337694943305481494/?alternatePartManufacturerId=0))

I would like to configure each server with 6X8GB + 6X2GB = 60GB memory each. I can't seem to find a configuration that will boot.

I am beginning to suspect that the Hynix memory is ECC registered memory RDIMM, and the Samsung memory is ECC unbuffered UDIMM memory, and so they will not mix but I am not sure of this from the data sheets.

I have tried in one of the servers and I can use 12X8GB = 96GB and extended memory tests run and pass over 24 hours. I can also use the 12X2GB = 24GB in the server and the extended memory tests run and pass over 24 hours. (I use UBCD and Memtest86 5.01 to run the memory testing.)

From what I can read in the technical guides [here](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-pedge-installing-upgrading-memory-11g.pdf) and [here](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-r610-tech-guidebook.pdf) the mixing of different sized memory should be possible. If so I gather the configuration would be:

```
[A1]-[A4]-[A2]-[A5]-[A3]-[A6]       [B1]-[B4]-[B2]-[B5]-[B3]-[B6]
 8GB  8GB  8GB  8GB  8GB  8GB        2GB  2GB  2GB  2GB  2GB  2GB
```

Would that be correct memory configuration?

Thanks!

### Answer (from Damon):

The particular rams I listed were incompatible to be used together but if they were compatible the best layout would have been:

```
[A1]-[A4]-[A2]-[A5]-[A3]-[A6]       [B1]-[B4]-[B2]-[B5]-[B3]-[B6]
 8GB  2GB  8GB  2GB  8GB  2GB        8GB  2GB  8GB  2GB  8GB  2GB
```

Comment: The Hynix is registered while the Samsung is unbuffered and you typically cannot mix the two.  I think you have identified your own problem.

Comment: @Damon, thanks. If the Samsung memory was compatible would the memory layout be as I listed?

Comment: Yeah, if it were compatible, the layout you listed would work. However, you should change it so that "lettered slots" are matching. Such as A1 and B1 having the same size of memory. When you get to A5 and B5, switch to the 2GB. This way you'll get dual channel interleave instead of single.